# What's wrong with the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

```
<html>

<head>

    <title> Random </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

        var typeFont = new Array ( "cooper","Fixedsys","Edwardian Script ITC", "Gill Sans MT", "Kozuka Gothic Pro", "Lucida Sans", "Adobe Gothic Std", "Adobe Naskh", "Algerian","Arial Unicode MS");

        function font()
        {
            head6.style.fontFamily = typeFont[ Math.floor( Math.random * 10 ) ];
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <center>
        <h1 onmouseover="font()" onmouseout="font" id="head6" > this is the text </h1>
    </center>

</body>
```

I am trying  to change the font every time the mouse is over or out and this function with `head6.style.fontFamily = typeFont[3]` but it doesn't with the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `NaN` as `Math.random` is a function and it can't be parsed to a number.

You have to call the funtion

```
Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 )
```

Note that this is fine as long as the array have exactly 10 indices, but you'd generally want to use the arrays length instead of `10`

Comment: `Math.random()*10` will be working correctly as `Math.random()` return a value from __0(inclusive)__ and __1(exclusive)__, and multiplying it by `10` will never give `10`. so `Math.floor()` of the largest value returned by `Math.random()*10` will give __9__.

Comment: That's what I said, it works as long as the array has 10 indices, if it has less or more indices it won't work properly, you'd have to change 10 to the arrays length, and that's why you often just see `Math.random() * array.length` as then it updates itself when the array is changed

Comment: Is it just me or is head6 not defined at all?? And using online functions is 90s bull. Use event listeners in a script not inline in HTML. There's actually a lot wrong with the OPs code in speed and logic. Correct me if I'm wrong adeneo

Comment: @EasyBB - `head6` is defined in the global scope because the element has that ID. I don't like to use those global properties at all, but they are defined in HTML5 and should be fine to use. Inline event handlers suck and should be avoided, and here the OP forgot the parentheses for the function in one of them as well. Also the `language` attribute was deprecated 10 years ago. I don't always change the entire code the OP is posting when it's something really simple like this, as I figure the most important thing is getting it working and showing a newbie where the problem is.

Comment: Oh I understand you reasoning adeneo just making sure my thought was correct lol.